# Is there a free-embedded SSH solution?

Tags: untagged

I'm working for an important company which has some severe network policies. I'd like to connect from my work, to my home linux server (mainly because it allows me to monitor my home-automated installation, but that's off-topic) but of course, any ssh connection (tcp port 22) to an external site is blocked. While I understand why this is done (to avoid ssh tunnels I guess), I really need to have some access to my box.

(Well, "**need**" might be exagerated, but that would be nice ;)

Do you know any web-based solution that I could install on my home linux server that would give me some pseudo-terminal (served using https) embedded in a web page ? I'm not necessarily looking for something graphical: a simple web-embedded ssh console would do the trick.

Or do you guys see any other solution that wouldn't compromise network security ?

Thank you very much for your solutions/advices.

`EDIT:`

Any solution able to work within apache2 would be even more adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) ?

You could also [create a SSH tunnel over HTTP](http://dag.wieers.com/howto/ssh-http-tunneling/) but your network admin probably doesn't want you to do that and it's overkill.

Comment: Yes ! ajaxterm seems to be the one. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe: http://www.javassh.org ?

Answer (score 0):

If they've got some severe policies then it's likely they have some serious sanctions (like firing you) for transgressions.  Ensure that you have got written permission to be monitoring your home on their time and using their equipment. Connect at your own expense using your own resources like a 3G card on a laptop or a smartphone is a better solution.

Comment: Yep, I thought of that. I've heard of some people here that setup icmp tunnels but I don't like it. I understand why those restrictions exists and that's why I don't want a direct link to be established between my work computer and my home. From my point of view, using a web-based solution is safer and more likely to be tolerated. Anyway, thank you for your advices.

Comment: I have logged into my home setup with my iPhone.  Typing is a pain, so I have short aliases for everything I usually type.  By doing that, I avoid all company equipment.  Does your job allow you iPhones or the equivalent?

Comment: Yep it does. Unfortunately I signed for 2 years with my current phone operator and can't change for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

If you're that concerned than I would suggest getting a mobile that's capable of running a terminal. iPhone + TouchTerm / TouchTerm Pro is my solution. I'm sure the same could be accomplished with an Android phone as well although I don't have any experience with that. This solution would also allow you to monitor your home installation from anywhere and not just work.

Comment: Well, unless the company forbids the use of personal phones ;) But for sure, yes: that is a nice solution in many (other) cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get around silly firewall rules, it's a direct link between computers whether it's over port 22 or port 443. The only significant difference is which port it's on. If you want to get REALLY sneaky, try [DNS](http://www.dnstunnel.de/) [tunnelling](http://thomer.com/howtos/nstx.html).

Answer (score -1):

Change the port of your ssh server to 443.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, my 443 TCP port is used by apache (and I can't go without it). But I just wonder, is there a way for a network administrator watching at the network traffic, to distinguish between a ssh on TCP/443 connection and a legitimate HTTPS connection ?

Comment: I havent got deep knowledge on the tcp stack, but they shouldn't be able to, as both are encrypted.

Comment: They can.  The first thing an SSH server does is send it's version string in cleartext, any basic Network IDS will redflag a SSH id string on a non-ssh port.